# Can I inject the dependency in groovy domain?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In My Project I'm using two database and the column name is different in both database. So I defined a flag in config file , and injected a dependency in domain.

Example:-->

```
class MRAffiliate {

    transient def grailsApplication;

    String companyName;

    String annotations;

    static mapping = {        
        table name: "affiliati"//, schema: "public"
        id generator:'sequence', params:[sequence:'affiliati_seq']
        id column: "id"//, sqlType: "int4";
        if (grailsApplication.config.com.dogmasystems.postgres==true){
            companyName column: "ragione_sociale";
        } else {
            companyName column: "ragione_sociale", sqlType: "string";
        }
        if (grailsApplication.config.com.dogmasystems.postgres==true){
            annotations column: "annotazioni";
        } else {
            annotations column: "annotazioni", sqlType: "string";
        } 
        version false;
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to define the column name according to database

I'm getting the error , while executing this code .
The error is,
"Error evaluating ORM mappings block for domain MRAffiliate  No such property: grailsApplication for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingBuilder"

Comment: @Szymon which grails version is this ?

Comment: grails version :2.4.4

Comment: You are trying to access an instance variable (`grailsApplication`) from within a static context (the `mapping` closure`).  You can't access any instance state from a static context.  The language doesn't allow it because it is non-sensical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Holders.grailsApplication.config.xxx` -- see [this domain class](https://github.com/snimavat/nimble/blob/master/grails-app/domain/grails/plugin/nimble/core/UserBase.groovy) which uses the config in mapping block.

Comment: Good to know its working for you.. please consider accepting the answer :)